# Android Leaderboard will not display

Tags: android, google-api, leaderboard

I do not have any errors when submitting my scores using:

```
public void submitScore(int score)
{
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, "leaderboard_easy_leaderboard", score);
}
```

but when I run my display leaderboard code:

```
public void displayScores()
{
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient, "leaderboard_easy_leaderboard"), 0);
}
```

I recieve the following errors:

```
11-07 17:00:39.873 32580-1830/? E/Volley: [161] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/leaderboard_easy_leaderboard?language=en_US

11-07 17:00:39.882 32580-9774/? E/LeaderboardAgent: Unable to retrieve leaderboard leaderboard_easy_leaderboard

11-07 17:00:39.882 32580-9774/? E/LeaderboardAgent: No instance found for leaderboard leaderboard_easy_leaderboard for SOCIAL and ALL_TIME
```

The googleapis link displays the following text:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was:

```
getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy_leaderboard)
```

Instead of:

```
"leaderboard_easy_leaderboard"
```

So the final solution was:

```
public void displayScores()
{
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy_leaderboard)), 0);
}
```